# Use log4j on a deployed war

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jboss, log4j

I've made a trivial RESTful service on a JBoss server that just says "hello" when it receives any request. This part works and it is already deployed.
To go further with my project I need to log. The other applications on the server use log4j configured by a log4j.xml placed on a specific folder on the server.
For an offline project I'm used to have a runnable main method that in this case I would use to execute `DOMConfigurator.configure(filepath)` (where filepath is the log4j.xml) and I will be expecting to log with those settings.
However, since this is a deployed service (and since I'm not skilled enough to figure it myself) how would I so such a thing?
The question in my opinion could be interpreted in two ways:

- How do I run some code "for sure" when I deploy something (in similar way to a main method) ? Do i need something like spring-boot?
- How do I setup log4j on a deployed service on JBoss?

(I don't know if one question excludes the other...)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you want to use a log4j.xml or do would you prefer using the logging subsystem in WildFly which would allow for runtime changes?

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to run some code "for sure" you can create @PostConstruct method in one of your beans. Both Spring and EJB support it.

2)As for log4J configuration it should be enough to put it in classpath and add corresponding dependencies, no explicit configuration of path should be needed.